# Having a issue with shopify resizing image from liquid file

Tags: shopify, liquid

Hello I'm trying to edit an image make it smaller or custom size but not familiar with liquid. Thank you for the help guys. I added some code. I think its default as certain percentage but not sure. Let me know if you guys need some extra code or information from me.

```js
    // settings_data.json file
    "index-newsletter": {
        "type": "index-newsletter",
        "settings": {
          "title": "Newsletter",
          "richtext": "<p>Subscribe to get special offers, free giveaways, and once-in-a-lifetime deals.<\/p>",
          "width": "full",
          "flex_align": "align--middle-left",
          "text_color": "dark",
          "height": "screen-height-one-third",
          "bg_image": "shopify:\/\/shop_images\/Grazioso_Logo321321_db2a67b3-d13f-4d64-a73d-c82f176fd6a5.png",
          "overlay_opacity": 50,
          "overlay_color": "#ffffff"
        }
      },
      
     
      <!-- /sections/newsletter.liquid -->
{%- assign img_url = section.settings.bg_image | img_url: '1x1' | replace: '_1x1.', '_{width}x.' -%}

<style>
  {%- if section.settings.text_color == 'white' -%}
    .index-newsletter-{{ section.id }},
    .index-newsletter-{{ section.id }} .input-group.newsletter-form input { color: #fff; }
  {%- endif -%}
</style>

<div class="index-newsletter index-newsletter-{{ section.id }}" data-section-id="{{ section.id }}" data-section-type="newsletter">
  <div class="wide-image js-overflow-container {{ section.settings.height }}"
    data-aos-duration="500"
    data-aos="fade-up">
    <div class="hero__content__wrapper hero__content--transparent {{ section.settings.flex_align }}">
      <div class="hero__content hero__content--{{ section.settings.width }} js-overflow-content">
        <div class="newsletter__content">
          {% if section.settings.title != '' %}
            <h5 class="newsletter__title">{{ section.settings.title }}</h5>
          {% endif %}
          {% if collection.description != '' %}
          <div class="rte">
            {{ section.settings.richtext }}
          </div>
          {% endif %}
          <div class="newsletter-signup">
             {% include 'newsletter-form' %}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    {% if section.settings.bg_image %}
      {% if section.settings.height == 'image-height' %}
        <img class="lazyload responsive-wide-image"
          alt="{{ section.settings.bg_image.alt | default: section.settings.title }}"
          src="{{ section.settings.bg_image | img_url: '18x'  }}"
          data-src="{{ img_url }}"
          data-widths="[180, 360, 540, 720, 900, 1080, 1296, 1512, 1728, 2048, 2450, 2700, 3000, 3350, 3750, 4100]"
          data-aspectratio="{{ section.settings.bg_image.aspect_ratio }}"
          data-parent-fit="cover"
          data-sizes="auto"/>
      {% else %}
        <div class="background-size-cover lazyload"  data-bgset="{% include 'bgset', image: section.settings.bg_image %}"></div>
      {% endif %}
      <noscript>
        <img src="{{ section.settings.bg_image | img_url: '1440x' }}" alt="{{ section.settings.bg_image.alt | default: collection.title }}" class="responsive-wide-image"/>
      </noscript>
      {% assign overlay_opacity = section.settings.overlay_opacity | times: 0.01 %}
      <div class="image-overlay" style="background-color:{{ section.settings.overlay_color }} !important; opacity:{{ overlay_opacity }};"></div>
    {% endif %}
  </div>
</div>

{% schema %}
{
  "name": "Newsletter",
  "settings": [
    {
      "type": "header",
      "content": "Content"
    },
    {
      "type": "text",
      "id": "title",
      "label": "Heading",
      "default": "Newsletter"
    },
    {
      "id": "richtext",
      "type": "richtext",
      "label": "Subheading",
      "default": "<p>Subscribe to get special offers, free giveaways, and once-in-a-lifetime deals.</p>"
    },
    {
      "type": "paragraph",
      "content": "Subscribers are under 'Accepts Marketing' in your [customer admin](/admin/customers)."
    },
    {
      "type": "select",
      "id": "width",
      "label": "Width",
      "default": "full",
      "options": [
        { "value": "full", "label": "Full" },
        { "value": "default", "label": "Default" }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "select",
      "id": "flex_align",
      "label": "Text alignment",
      "default": "align--middle-left",
      "options": [
        { "value": "align--middle-left", "label": "Left" },
        { "value": "align--middle-center", "label": "Center" },
        { "value": "align--middle-right", "label": "Right" }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "select",
      "id": "text_color",
      "label": "Text color",
      "default": "dark",
      "options": [
        { "value": "dark", "label": "Dark" },
        { "value": "white", "label": "White" }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "select",
      "id": "height",
      "label": "Section height",
      "default": "screen-height-one-third",
      "options": [
        { "value": "screen-height-one-half", "label": "1/2 of screen"},
        { "value": "screen-height-one-third", "label": "1/3 of screen"},
        { "value": "five-fifty-height-hero ", "label": "550px" },
        { "value": "four-fifty-height-hero", "label": "450px" },
        { "value": "three-fifty-height-hero", "label": "350px" },
        { "value": "two-fifty-height-hero", "label": "250px" },
        { "value": "image-height", "label": "Image height" }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "header",
      "content": "Background"
    },
    {
      "type": "image_picker",
      "id": "bg_image",
      "label": "Background image"
    },
    {
      "type": "range",
      "id": "overlay_opacity",
      "label": "Opacity",
      "info": "Increase contrast for legible text.",
      "unit": "%",
      "min": 0,
      "max": 90,
      "step": 5,
      "default": 0
    },
    {
      "type": "color",
      "id": "overlay_color",
      "label": "Overlay color",
      "default": "#fff"
    }
  ],
  "presets": [
    {
      "category": "Promotional",
      "name": "Newsletter"
    }
  ]
}
{% endschema %}
```

Comment: You need check into your theme code, and `{%- assign img_url = section.settings.bg_image | img_url: '1x1' | replace: '_1x1.', '_{width}x.' -%}
`, this lines create an issue I think you need to check with it.

Comment: @Onkar what do you mean by theme code? i thought this code is the newsletter section, which is where I want to resize my photo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 {% if section.settings.bg_image %}
  {% if section.settings.height == 'image-height' %}
    <img class="lazyload responsive-wide-image"
      alt="{{ section.settings.bg_image.alt | default: section.settings.title }}"
      src="{{ section.settings.bg_image | img_url: '18x'  }}"
      data-src="{{ img_url }}"
      data-widths="[180, 360, 540, 720, 900, 1080, 1296, 1512, 1728, 2048, 2450, 2700, 3000, 3350, 3750, 4100]"
      data-aspectratio="{{ section.settings.bg_image.aspect_ratio }}"
      data-parent-fit="cover"
      data-sizes="auto"/>
  {% else %}
    <div class="background-size-cover lazyload"  data-bgset="{% include 'bgset', image: section.settings.bg_image %}"></div>
  {% endif %}


{
  "type": "select",
  "id": "height",
  "label": "Section height",
  "default": "screen-height-one-third",
  "options": [
    { "value": "screen-height-one-half", "label": "1/2 of screen"},
    { "value": "screen-height-one-third", "label": "1/3 of screen"},
    { "value": "five-fifty-height-hero ", "label": "550px" },
    { "value": "four-fifty-height-hero", "label": "450px" },
    { "value": "three-fifty-height-hero", "label": "350px" },
    { "value": "two-fifty-height-hero", "label": "250px" },
    { "value": "image-height", "label": "Image height" }
  ]
},
```

in the theme editing, if you choose the height setting to `image height`. These will happen

because you are using lazyload, there will be a small picture of 18px used, hence this line `src="{{ section.settings.bg_image | img_url: '18x'  }}"`
the picture will automatically resize base on the screen width;
`data-widths="[180, 360, 540, 720, 900, 1080, 1296, 1512, 1728, 2048, 2450, 2700, 3000, 3350, 3750, 4100]"`

if you want to have the image at max-width 2048, just remove the the number from data-width;  I.e. I only want image size 180 - 2048.  I will remove 2450, 2700, 3000, ...

another solution is to add max-width to the image;i.e add `style="max-width: 500px"` to the img tag

```
{% if section.settings.bg_image %}
  {% if section.settings.height == 'image-height' %}
    <img class="lazyload responsive-wide-image"
      alt="{{ section.settings.bg_image.alt | default: section.settings.title }}"
      src="{{ section.settings.bg_image | img_url: '18x'  }}"
      data-src="{{ img_url }}"
      data-widths="[180, 360, 540, 720, 900, 1080, 1296, 1512, 1728, 2048, 2450, 2700, 3000, 3350, 3750, 4100]"
      data-aspectratio="{{ section.settings.bg_image.aspect_ratio }}"
      data-parent-fit="cover"
      data-sizes="auto"/
      style="max-width: 500px;">
  {% else %}
    <div class="background-size-cover lazyload"  data-bgset="{% include 'bgset', image: section.settings.bg_image %}"></div>
  {% endif %}
```

Comment: I changed max-width it did changged image size but image went right. I was wondering do you know how to centerize this `div` image?

Comment: `<div class="background-size-cover lazyload"  data-bgset="{% include 'bgset', image: section.settings.bg_image %}"></div>` this was where I had to add max-width but picture is align to right side

Comment: if you are using image as the background then use " background-position: center;"

Comment: Using `{{ img_url }}` as the data-src won't just grab the imageDrop object instead of the actual image URL? I'm using lazysizes and it doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: img_url declared at the top. using replaceUrlParam.min.js to replace the _{width}x with the data-widths.